# Javascript Closures Exercise

Tags: javascript, closures

Got this exercise from school:

Implement the calculate function that returns an object that gives the ability to perform the four mathematical operations (sum, subtraction, multiplication, and division) on the same number and finally prints the result.

TIP: To concatenate the methods just return the reference to the object itself ($this)

Example:

calculator
.add(2) // 2
.add(4) // 6
.multiply(3) // 18
.sub(1) // 17
.sub(3) // 14
.divide(2) // 7
.printResult();

What I did:

```
function calculate() {

  let result = 0;
  
  let calculator = {
    add: function(number) {
      return result += number;
    },
    multiply: function(number) {
      return result *= number;
    },
    sub: function(number) {
      return result -= number;
    },
    divide: function(number) {
      return result /= number;
    },
    printResult: function() {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return calculator;
  
}

const calculator = calculate();
calculator.add(2).add(4).multiply(3).sub(1).sub(3).divide(2).printResult(); // The result will be: 7
```

Please help me I know it's wrong but I did not understand closures with objects. Also give me explanations.

Comment: You are chaining calls but you are not returning the same object, you should change your functions (printResult is fine) to work like `result += number; return calculator;`

Comment: you need to return `this` on the methods, which is the object itself

Answer (score 1):

The calculator methods `add`, `multiply`...etc should return the calculator object (which is `this`), not the result. So with a minor modification, it will work

```js
function calculate() {
  let result = 0;
  
  let calculator = {
    add: function(number) {
      result += number;
      return this;
    },
    multiply: function(number) {
      result *= number;
      return this;
    },
    sub: function(number) {
      result -= number;
      return this;
    },
    divide: function(number) {
      result /= number;
      return this;
    },
    printResult: function() {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return calculator;
}

const calculator = calculate();
let result = calculator.add(2).add(4).multiply(3).sub(1).sub(3).divide(2).printResult(); 
// The result will be: 7
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Should the chained functions return `this` or `calculator` (what should be the result of `.add.bind(otherObj, 2)()`)

Comment: @nick, this would be a question for the Asker. There is no mention of what should happen when another `this` is bound, but in the challenge description there is the hint to use `this`, so I suppose this is what they are looking for.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just curious as to what you would expect to happen in this case if it were a "black box"?